# UIViewのアニメーションを連続で実行させるにはどうすれば良いですか。

Tags: swift, ios

iOSアプリの開発において、以下のメソッドを使ってUIViewをアニメーションさせています。

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
    view.center = CGPoint(10, 10) // アニメーションの内容
}, completion: { _ in
    // アニメーション終了時の処理        
})
```

このようなアニメーションを連続で行いたい場合に、どのように書けばよいでしょうか。
以下のようにこのメソッドを入れ子にすることで、一応希望の動作を得ることはできましたが、アニメーションの数が増えるにつれてどんどんネストが深くなり、読みにくいコードになってしまい、望ましい書き方ではないような気がしています。

```
// viewの中心座標を(10, 10), (110, 110), (20, 20), (120, 120)の順番に1秒ずつかけて動かす
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
    view.center = CGPoint(10, 10)
}, completion: { _ in
    // 終了時に新しいアニメーションを始める
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
        view.center = CGPoint(110, 110)
    }, completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
            view.center = CGPoint(20, 20)
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
                view.center = CGPoint(120, 120)
            }, completion: { _ in
                // 全てのアニメーションが終了
            })
        })
    })
})
```

どのように書くべきか、またはこの書き方をするしかないのか、教えて頂ければ幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

連続したアニメーションを実行する別の書き方としてキーフレームアニメーションがあります。
キーフレームアニメーションのAPIはいくつかありますが、ご提示のコードと同じ動きをさせるには、Core AnimationのAPIを利用します。

Core Animationでは`UIView`ではなく`CALayer`のプロパティに対してアニメーションを指定するので、`center`の代わりに`position`を使用します。

また、アニメーションと実際のビューの移動は独立しているので、アニメーションが終了した後の位置をあらかじめビューにセットしておく必要があります（そうでなければ、アニメーションが終了したところで元の位置に戻ってしまう）。

どちらが見やすいかは好みだと思います。別にコールバックでネストしていく書き方でも問題ないと思います。

```
view.center = CGPoint(x: 120, y: 120)

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.values = [NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)),
                    NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 110)),
                    NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)),
                    NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 120))]
animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
animation.duration = 4
animation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut),
                             CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut),
                             CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut),
                             CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut),
                             CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)]
view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "")
```

キーフレームアニメーションには`UIView`のAPIもあり、同様のコードは下記のようにも書けます。ただし、このAPIはキーフレームごとにアニメーションカーブを設定できず、全体の時間に対するアニメーションカーブになるので、このままでは元のコードの動きとは若干異なります。それが問題なければ、下記の書き方が、標準のAPIでは見やすいと思います。

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.25) {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.25) {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: 110, y: 110)
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.25) {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.75, relativeDuration: 0.25) {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: 120, y: 120)
    }
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `UIView`の書き方では、`completion`の中で、次のアニメーションを始める前に何らかの処理を書くことができました(変数の値を変えたり、アニメーションとは関係ない`UILabel`のテキストを変更したりなど)。Core Animationでも、アニメーションとアニメーションの間のタイミングに簡易的に何かの処理を実行させるようなことは出来るのでしょうか。このような目的では素直に`UIView`のアニメーションを使うべきでしょうか。

Comment: ものによりますけどUIViewのAPIを使ったほうが簡単そうに思います。